# Dynamically creating SVG path in JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I cannot manage to get the following code to work. I am trying to dynamically generate the following SVG in JS:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="m12.45 37.65-2.1-2.1L21.9 24 10.35 12.45l2.1-2.1L24 21.9l11.55-11.55 2.1 2.1L26.1 24l11.55 11.55-2.1 2.1L24 26.1Z"/></svg>
```

I have tried:

```js
let closeButton = document.createElement("svg");
closeButton.setAttribute("height", "48");
closeButton.setAttribute("width", "48");
let closeButtonPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"path"); 
closeButtonPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "m12.45 37.65-2.1-2.1L21.9 24 10.35 12.45l2.1-2.1L24 21.9l11.55-11.55 2.1 2.1L26.1 24l11.55 11.55-2.1 2.1L24 26.1Z");
closeButton.appendChild(closeButtonPath);
this.#form.appendChild(closeButton);
```

Comment: Try `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @enxaneta: **your code has errors:**

For creating `svg` elements you need

**`createElementNS()`** instead of `createElement()`

Besides, `this.#form` is not a valid selector
Rather use something like this:

```
let form = document.getElementById('form');
form.appendChild(closeButton);
```

```js
const ns ="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

let closeIconSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
closeIconSvg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 48 48");
closeIconSvg.classList.add('closeIconSvg');

let closeIconPath = document.createElementNS(ns,"path"); 
closeIconPath.setAttribute("d", "m12.45 37.65 -2.1-2.1L21.9 24 10.35 12.45l2.1-2.1L24 21.9l11.55-11.55 2.1 2.1L26.1 24l11.55 11.55-2.1 2.1L24 26.1Z");
closeIconSvg.appendChild(closeIconPath);

//let form = document.getElementById('form');
let closeButton = document.getElementById('btnClose');
closeButton.appendChild(closeIconSvg);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}

.form{
  font-size:48px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

input, 
.btnClose{
  margin:0;
  padding:0.15em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
  font-size:1em;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
}

.closeIconSvg{
  width:auto;
  height:1em;
  vertical-align: -0.25em;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form" action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name">
  <button  id="btnClose" class="btnClose" type="button"></button>
</form>
```

I highly recommend to use more semantic variable names:

Since your icon's parent svg is not the actual button – you better use a self explanatory name like "closeIconSvg".

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it "the lazy way" in 1 line (except if you have variables for width, height and path)?:)

```js
let svg_str = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48px" height="48px"><path d="m12.45 37.65-2.1-2.1L21.9 24 10.35 12.45l2.1-2.1L24 21.9l11.55-11.55 2.1 2.1L26.1 24l11.55 11.55-2.1 2.1L24 26.1Z"/></svg>';
document.querySelector('#button1').innerHTML = svg_str;


// if height and widht has to be changed otherwise you put them directly in svg_str
const h = 48 + 'px';
const w = 48 + 'px';
// if path is a variable otherwise you put directly in svg_str
const path_d = "m12.45 37.65-2.1-2.1L21.9 24 10.35 12.45l2.1-2.1L24 21.9l11.55-11.55 2.1 2.1L26.1 24l11.55 11.55-2.1 2.1L24 26.1Z";

svg_str = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '"><path d="' + path_d + '"/></svg>';
document.querySelector('#button2').innerHTML = svg_str;
```

```html
<div id="button1">

</div>
<div id="button2">

</div>
```

Comment: 1/10, wouldn't get into an art gallery

Comment: _“Art is in the eye of the beholder, and everyone will have their own interpretation.”_

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> “Art is in the eye of the beholder, and everyone will have their own interpretation.”
> ― E.A. Bucchianeri

```html
<style>
  svg-icon { background:pink }
</style>

<svg-icon></svg-icon>
<svg-icon width="80"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon width="180"></svg-icon>

<script>
customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    let width = (this.getAttribute("width") || 48) + "px";
    this.innerHTML =`<svg width="${width}" height="${width}" viewBox="0 0 48 44">`
                    + `<path d="m12.4 37.6-2.1-2.1 11.6-11.5-11.6-11.6 2.1-2.1 11.6 11.6 11.6-11.6 2.1 2.1-11.6 11.6 11.6 11.6-2.1 2.1-11.6-11.6z"/>`
                    + `</svg>`;
  }
});
</script>
```